# $(P\Lambda P^{-1}=T^2)~\implies~(\exists \Lambda'~\text{s.t.}~T=R\Lambda' R^{-1})$: $\;P,R\;$ Unitary Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a linear operator such that the operator $T^2$ is diagonalizable. Is $T$ necessarily diagonalizable?

Comment: Is my title legit? Or does it not make sense. I mean think before you comment...

Comment: I have thought a lot before writing this, and your title looks legit.

Comment: I know, but you have a reputation.

Comment: I'm curious.  The question itself (not the title) says nothing about matrices or finite-dimensional vector spaces.  Is there a notion of diagonalizability for maps between infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Answer (score 4):

No. Counterexamples are plentiful, but the mother of them all has to be the non-diagonalisable Jordan block
$$
T := \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
which squares to $T^2 = 0$.

Comment: Nilpotent... Wait what does nilpotent mean?

Comment: Were you taught in the UK?

Comment: No, I'm a Canadian; our spelling is a not-particularly-well-defined hybrid of British and American spelling, though I myself tend to err somewhat on the side of the British spelling.

As for the word "nilpotent," one says that an operator $A$ is nilpotent if there exists some positive integer $n$ such that $A^n = 0$. In the case of $T$, one can take $n=2$.